# Trying to create a fetch request with react hooks, my data is still null

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Relatively new to using hooks, but I create this useFetch hook and I am trying to sign in a user after getting their information from text fields, I am able to create a successful request by hard coding `{email:someemail, password: somepassword}` but the issue arises when I am trying to grab the input from my state.

The error states I am missing a parameter
Here is my component:

```
const Login: FunctionComponent = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  // @ts-ignore
  const postData =useData({email:email, password:password})
  const thisWorks = useData({email:"someEmail", password:"somePassword"})
  return (
    <>
    {console.log(thisWorks)}
    <TextFieldComponent
      isRequired={true}
      label={'Email'}
      value={email}
      // @ts-ignore
      handleChange={(e)=> setEmail(e.target.value) }
    />
    <TextFieldComponent
    isRequired={true}
    label={'Password'}
    value={password}
    // @ts-ignore
    handleChange={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value) }
  />
  <Button
    onClick={() => postData}
    text="Login"
    />
  </>
  )
}
```

And here is my query:

```
const useData = (data: loginInfo): QueryType[] | string => {
  const fetched = useFetch<Query>(
    "example.com",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }
  );
  if (fetched.status === "loading") {
    return fetched.status;
  } else if (fetched.status === "loaded") {
    const { payload } = fetched;
    // @ts-ignore
    return payload;
  } else if (fetched.status === "error") {
    return fetched.status;
  }
  return "Error";
};
```

my useFetch Hook:

```
const useFetch = <T>(url: string, headers?: Header | any) => {
  const isCurrent = useRef(true);
  const [result, setResult] = useState<Service<T>>({
    status: "loading",
  });
  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      // called when the component is going to unmount
      isCurrent.current = false;
    },
    []
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url, headers)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((response) => setResult({ status: "loaded", payload: response }))
      .catch((error) => setResult({ status: "error", error }));
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
  return result;
};
```

Comment: Could you post the code for your useFetch hook? I think the issue is you aren't using a useEffect hook which will cause a rerender when the data changes. See https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-custom-usefetch-react-hook for reference!

Comment: Great! Check out my answer, your issue I believe is that the useData is just a pure function so is not getting called again after the initial load. Check out my answer, which should be all you need to get both the status and response!

Comment: doesnt seem to work still not getting my data back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious to ask,
will you send many API requests while you typing email and password?

```
<Button
  onClick={() => postData}
  text="Login"
/>
```

this code doesn't seem to work, `postData` is not a function, just an object

may be you can modify your code like this (I'm not tested just sample code)

your component

```js
const Login: FunctionComponent = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const login = useFetch('http://path/to/login', { method: 'POST' })

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (login.status === 'loaded') {
      // do your stuff
    }
  }, [login.status])

  const handleLogin = () => {
    login.setPayload({ email, password })
  }

  if (login.status === 'loading') {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  if (login.status === 'error') {
    return <div>{login.error}</div>
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TextFieldComponent
        isRequired={true}
        label={'Email'}
        value={email}
        // @ts-ignore
        handleChange={(e)=> setEmail(e.target.value) }
      />
      <TextFieldComponent
        isRequired={true}
        label={'Password'}
        value={password}
        // @ts-ignore
        handleChange={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value) }
      />
      <Button
        onClick={handleLogin}
        text="Login"
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

useFetch

```js
const useFetch = <T>(url: string, options: RequestInit) => {
  const [payload, setPayload] = React.useState({})
  const [start, setStart] = React.useEffect(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!start) {
      return
    }

    fetch(url, {
      ...options,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        ...options.headers
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((response) => setResult({ status: "loaded", payload: response }))
      .catch((error) => setResult({ status: "error", error }))
      .finally(() => setStart(false))
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [url, start, payload, options]);

  return {
    ...result,
    setPayload: (payload) => {
      setPayload(payload)
      setStart(true)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a way not to send do many API requests? Im trying to prevent rerenders

Comment: ahh, in your code will not trigger re-render because you're not put url and headers in your deps array of effects

Comment: yea I tried originally putting my url and headers in the useEffect but I get an endless loop, Ill try out this implementation

Comment: ok, you can also take a look at this article https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

Comment: This did it, Im gonna need to modify it to fit the existing API but this was it! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be written using the useEffect hook

```
    const useFetch = (url, options) => {
      const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null);
      const [status, setStatus] = React.useState("loading");

      useEffect(async () => {
       try {
          const res = await fetch(url, options);
          const json = await res.json();
          setResponse(json);
          setStatus("success");
        } catch (error) {
        setStatus("error");
       }
      });
      return [status, response];
    };
```

Comment: I am using a useEffect hook already, but I think my issue might be with the useEffect